# Using a template function pointer inside another template function

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, pybind11

I'm using a template functions to add several function to my python module generated by pybind11.

The following simplified code compiles nicely with MSVC.
Yet compilation with gcc-6.3 fails if the (decltype ...) conversion is left commented.

I'm confused because this conversion seems useless to me: if the compiler is able to deduce the type using decltype it should be able to do it without it. Is this a gcc bug ?

```cpp
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

template <typename T>
auto f() { /* do something */ };

template <typename T>
void add_function(py::module& module, const char *name)
{
    module.def(name, /*(decltype(&f<T>))*/ &f<T>);
}

PYBIND11_PLUGIN(Foo)
{
    py::module module("Foo", "");
    add_function<int>(module, "f");
    return module.ptr();
}
```

Here what gcc outputs when it fails to compile (cf. also the link below by W.F. that produces the same type of output without pybind11):

```
./foo.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void add_function(pybind11::module&, const char*) [with T = int]’:
./foo.cpp:17:31:   required from here
./foo.cpp:11:2: error: no matching function for call to ‘pybind11::module::def(const char*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)’
  module.def(name, /*(decltype(&f<T>))*/ &f<T>);
  ^~~~~~
In file included from ./foo.cpp:1:0:
/home/simon/local/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:732:13: note: candidate: template<class Func, class ... Extra> pybind11::module& pybind11::module::def(const char*, Func&&, const Extra& ...)
     module &def(const char *name_, Func &&f, const Extra& ... extra) {
             ^~~
/home/simon/local/include/pybind11/pybind11.h:732:13: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
./foo.cpp:11:2: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘Func’
  module.def(name, /*(decltype(&f<T>))*/ &f<T>);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3UgN7KsefeRCnsMv) would be close to mcve, looks like clang doesn't have a problem with the code only gcc.

Comment: This looks like [gcc bug 64194](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=64194).  From that report, it looks like another workaround is to add `(void) f<T>;` before attempting to bind it.